# PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014

Tags: mysql, pentaho

After doing all the set up for mysql repository for pentaho  bi-server 6.1. Here is what I got when I restart the server:
" The following errors were detected
One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener

Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.

Answer (score 2):

In systemListener.xml file you need to comment the following lines:

```
<!--<bean id="pooledDataSourceSystemListener" class="org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceSystemListener" />-->
<!--bean id="dynamicallyPooledDataSourceSystemListener" class="org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener" />
```